# Is it a runout if both the batsmen have reached the same end and at the same end the stump is broken?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

The situation is as below:

```
-------|----------------------------
       |
 stump |batsmen2 
 broken|batsmen1
 here  | 
-------|----------------------------
```

Is it a runout in the above situation?

Answer (score 3):

If both batsmen are on the same crease, then in order to get a wicket, fielders must have to break wickets of the other end. In that case, from those two batsmen, the batsman who had reached later to the first side of the crease gets out.

Answer (score 1):

[Law 38 (Run out)](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-38-run-out/) states that a batsman is out if:

> (i) he is out of his ground
>   and (ii) his wicket is fairly put down by the action of a fielder.

The batsman that is out of his ground has not had his wicket put down, therefore he is not out. The batsman that has had his wicket put down is in his ground, therefore he is also not out.